# destructuring a map as function input

Tags: clojure, pattern-matching, destructuring

let us say that I have a simple map

```
(def mymap {:a 1 :b 2 :c 3 :d 4})
```

Now I want to write a function called get-c. This function will get mymap as the input. Now since I am only interested in :c is there way to only get c already during the input stage? I have tried many variations but I always get an error. e.g.

```
(defn get-c [[{:keys [c]} input-map]] c)
```

It does compile but when I try (get-c mymap) I get

```
IllegalArgumentException Parameter declaration "mymap" should be a vector  clojure.core/assert-valid-fdecl/fn--7207 (core.clj:7187)
```

Thanks.
Eitan

Comment: There's no way that error message comes from the code you pasted. You'd get an error like that if you'd written, for example, `(defn get-c (mymap))`, and you'd get it when evaluating the `defn`, not when calling `get-c`. Please include the code you are actually running.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(defn get-c [{:keys [c]}] c)
```

You added too many `[]` so clojure was trying to destruct a vector.

Answer (score 0):

```
(defn get-c [{c :c}] c)
```

Here is a good reference for [destructuring](https://gist.github.com/john2x/e1dca953548bfdfb9844).

Answer (score 0):

Destructing Maps in Clojure is a very convenient and powerful feature. You can destruct the keys, rename the keys and also provide default values for keys.

```
(defn destruct-test
  [{:keys [name company]
    :as zmap
    :or {name "Default Name"
         company "Default Company"}}]
  [name company])
```